# a code for infix to postfix conversion

Tags: c++, infix-notation

I have written a code for infix to postfix conversion,This piece of code is not encountering any kind of compile time error but after taking the input infix expression it is giving some runtime errors which i am unable to understand these errors are something related to string as the message says.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

#define N 50
using namespace std;

class stack
{
private:
    char arr[N];
    int tos;

public:
    void push(char p)
    {
        if (tos != N)
            arr[++tos] = p;
        else
            cout << "stack full";
    }

    char pop()
    {
        if (tos == -1)
            cout << "stack Empty";
        else
            return (arr[tos--]);
    }

    bool isempty()
    {
        if (tos == -1)
            return (true);
        else 
            return (false);
    }

    char top()
    {
        return arr[tos];
    }

    stack()
    {
        tos = -1;
    }
};

int pres(char sym)
{
    if (sym == '^')
        return 3;
    else if (sym == '*' || '/')
        return 2;
    else if (sym == '+' || '-')
        return 1;
    else if (sym == '(')
        return 0;
} 

bool isoperator(char op)
{
    if (op=='+' || op=='-' || op=='/' || op=='*' || op=='^')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main()
{
    string infix, postfix;
    stack s;
    int in=0;
    int post=0;

    cout << "Enter an infix expression: ";
    cin >> infix;
    s.push('(');
    infix.append(")");
    char temp;

    while (!(s.isempty()))
    {
        if (isdigit(infix[in]))
            postfix[post++] = infix[in];
        else if (infix[in] == '(')
            s.push(infix[in]);
        else if (infix[in] == ')')
        {
            while (1)
            {
                temp = s.pop();
                if (temp == '(')
                    break;
                else
                    postfix[post] = infix[in];
            }
        }
        else if (isoperator(infix[in]))
        {
            while (pres(s.top()) >= pres(infix[in]))
                postfix[post++] = s.pop();

            s.push(infix[in]);
        }
        in++;
    }

    cout << "Postfix expression is: " << postfix;
    system("pause");

}
```

I m unable to get what's wrong with it. Can any one help??

Comment: "after taking the input infix expression it is giving some compile time errors": if those errors comes up after compiling, they are not compile-time errors, if they come up while executing the program they are runtime-errors. anyway, which expression did you enter ? what was the result ? how did it differ from what you expected ?

Comment: I think he means runtime error, as I have successfully compiled it. I took the liberty of editing it.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following logical errors in your code:

- the result string `postfix` is empty at the beginning, but you're writing to single character positions using `postfix[post++]=`. This is not valid and is propably causing the "string related" errors. You should only use `postfix.push_back()` to add characters to the output string.
- In the first inner `while` loop (`while(1)`) the last statement should read

  `postfix.push_back(temp);`

  since you want to append the operators from the stack to the output.
- Your code falsely accept input with unbalanced additional closing parents like "1+4)". Personally, I would put the input position as outer loop condition and verify that the stack is empty after the loop (and check for empty stack in the `pop()` function) for detecting input errors.

Comment: It should be postfix[post++] = temp;  append() is only for string.

Comment: Actually, it should be `postfix.push_back()` :) `postfix[post++]=temp` accesses a position which is outside the current string length which results in undefined behaviour (which means, it might work on some systems e.g. for short inputs, but will fail sooner or later with a segfault ...)

Answer (score 1):

The biggest error is in his pres() function, it should be:

```
else if (sym == '*' || sym == '/')
else if (sym == '+' || sym == '-')
```

I have noticed some of the errors mentioned by MartinStettner.

Comment: I found after fixing this error, and the first two points made by MartinStettner, the program works.